# How to get all stock symbols that have been listed for a given period

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, stock, yfinance

I'm pretty new to financial data and all API that exist out there. I want to get list of all tickers that have been listed for a given period of time (eg: at least 1 year).

I can get that using Yahoo Finance API for a given Ticker like

```
import yfinance as yf
tickerData = yf.Ticker('MSFT')
tickerDf = tickerData.history(period='1d', start='1900-1-1', end='1900-1-25')
 - MSFT: Data doesn't exist for startDate = -2208989361, endDate = -2206915761
```

Is there a way to run a script to filter all tickers from Nasdaq/NYSE and get me what I need without pulling to much data(history)?

Comment: Here is an article with 5 stock market APIs: https://towardsdatascience.com/best-5-free-stock-market-apis-in-2019-ad91dddec984. It mentions yfinance first. To pull less data, you might use weekly or monthly instead of daily.

Comment: As it is uncommon probably the specific is not available as API, closest I could find was https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#iex-symbols